# Round Double value in swift with addition before decimal

Tags: swift, double

i have double value `70514.94971385633`, now I want it to round the value and make it `70515.00`. I have tried command `rounded()`, but it only rounds value after the decimal. How I can round value after the decimal and add the nearest value to a number before decimal? this is my code for rounding the value,

```
let totalBidValue = self.minBid / usdToAED!
let roundedValue = totalBidValue.rounded()
```

but it shows result `70514.95`, i want it to add it before decimal value like `70515.00`

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? If `totalBidValue` is `70514.94971385633`  then  `totalBidValue.rounded()` becomes `70515.00` and not `70514.95`. – A [mcve] demonstrating the problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just small change in your code

```
let totalBidValue = self.minBid / usdToAED!

let roundedValue = totalBidValue.round()
```

or

```
let roundedValue = totalBidValue.rounded(.up)
```

Comment: Yeah this is what i want thanks bro. @Kishan Bhatiya

Answer (score 1):

Use **`ceil(_:)`** to get that working,

```
let value = 70514.94971385633
let result = ceil(value)
print(result) //70515.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `round()`

```
let myDoubleValue = 70514.94971385633
let roundedOffValue = round(myDoubleValue)

print(roundedOffValue) // 70515.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost perfect...

```
let totalBidValue = self.minBid / usdToAED!
let roundedValue = totalBidValue.rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)
```

just add `.toNearestOrAwayFromZero` in your code